# Change portion of URL to show different data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datatables

[JSFiddle Code](https://jsfiddle.net/thatgreg/03tmk8bj/11/)

In this code, I parse data from a JSON url into a table.

When a certain portion of the URL becomes altered, different search results come out. So I'm trying to give the user an option to input a different keyword that will bring different results.

In python I would use a f string request, is there a similar option in JavaScript?

Python example:

```
device_name = simpledialog.askstring(title="510K Database",
prompt="Enter Keyword:")

r = requests.get(f'https://api.fda.gov/device/510k.json?search=device_name:{device_name}&limit=1000')`
```

My JavaScript code

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: 'https://api.fda.gov/device/510k.json?search=device_name:glucose&limit=1000',
      dataSrc: 'results',
      cache: true,
    },
```

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would prompt and then use that variable as a template literal in your URL

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#echo').click(function() {
    $('.error').empty();
    let keyword = $('#keyword').val().trim();
    if (!keyword) return $(this).prev('.error').html("Please enter a keyword first");
    console.log(`The keyword is ${keyword}`);
    /* let table = $('#example').DataTable({
      ajax: {
        url: `https://api.fda.gov/device/510k.json?search=device_name:${keyword}&limit=1000`,
        dataSrc: 'results',
        cache: true,
      },
      // ....
    })
*/
  })

})
```

```css
.error {
  color: #f00;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>510k Database // Enter Keyword
<input id="keyword" />
</label>
<div class='error'></div>
<button id='echo'>Click me</button>
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for thanks. instead of getting the prompt to pop up, is it possible to enter the keyword into the button i included in html?                         
`<input id="myInput" value="">
<button id="myButton" onclick="javascript:alert('Data Shows Here')">Enter</button>`

Comment: Beware: This example is vulnerable to code injection.

Comment: @Tibrogargan - can you elaborate, or maybe give an example of the risk with this example?

Comment: Is there a better way? i was having a hard time getting the (updated) above code to run.

Comment: Craig. Into the button itself without any other scripts?

Comment: @Kinglish the value entered by the user should be limited to a known set of characters to prevent unintended modifications.  i.e.  entering things like `keyword&delete=true&foo=bar&whatever=whatever` would succeed.  Consequences of not preventing this depends on the backend implementation, but they could range from unauthorized exposure of data through denial of service to corrupted data.

Comment: sorry i didnt follow. right now the prompt pop up works somewhat fine. but id like to be able to just enter the code/keyword into the html button if possible

Comment: @Craig that doesn't make a huge amount of sense.  Buttons typically don't allow inputting of data.  Do you maybe mean something like having a text field that fires off the search when it's changed?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/thatgreg/03tmk8bj/14/ ---- in this code, whatever you enter in the pop prompt changes the parameters of the URL. I was hoping the HTML button could sync to do the same thing (so i wouldnt need the pop up). but maybe its not possible

Comment: Right, I get that - but an `<input type='button'>` element does not allow users to enter a value.  You're either going to need a prompt, or a text field, or a drop down list or something that allows the user to actually change the value - not just fire an event.

Comment: Ok, that's what this example is/does